# xslt: Preserve all elemenent and tags in node after substring

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to match a node, and substring a part of these from specific char to the end of nodes
for example in this code:

```
.........
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<body>
 <div class="todo">
  <p class="commission">1. shop at the <b>supermarket</b> when the weather <i>is nice</i></p>
  <p class="letter"><i>a)</i> buy chocolate <b>biscuits</b></p>
  <p class="number"><b>2.</b> after <red>doing</red> all the<blue>things</blue>, <i>go and refuel</i> the car</p>
 </div> 
</body>
```

I need to get an output like this, keeping everything from the space after the dot at the end of the tag:

```
<body>
 <parte>
  <num>1.</num>
  <p> shop at the <b>supermarket</b> when the weather <i>is nice</i></p>
 </parte>
 <parte>
  <num><i>a)</i></num>
  <p> buy chocolate <b>biscuits</b></p>
 </parte>
 <parte>
  <num><b>2.</b></num>
  <p> after <red>doing</red> all the<blue>things</blue>, <i>go and refuel</i> the car</p>
 </parte>
</body>
```

I tried to do it with standard substring-after or substring-before instruction but without result, i need to preserve all node inside p tag

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe perform the `substring()` on the first `text()` child of the `p`...

```
<xsl:template match="p[@class=('commission','letter','number')]/text()[1]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Updated fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzPZ/2

Comment: thank you a lot, good workaround but if i have also a tag in first part of text, for example in a) letter and i need to use also this element in other node , how i can do? anyway i need to have as example, tag letter without a) text.
exist in xst a way taht i can use for maipulate a part of text and preserve html tag in node with substring instruction? Please See my new example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzPZ/3

Comment: anyway i don't know how many child i have, i need a generic way to preserve node inside tag but substring content from poin to point

Comment: @H725 - Try changing `text()` to `node()`. Updated fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BS/1